# What are advantages of "meta-models"?

Tags: regression, logistic

Suppose you want to create a credit score that differentiates risk between different applicants. What are the advantages of having multiple sub models that are combined to generate the final score versus a single model that just includes all of the variables in the multiple submodels?

Comment: Does this:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373890/separate-models-vs-flags-in-the-same-model  answer your question?